# Genetic algebras; what should a mathematician know about them?

Tags: abstract-algebra, biology

I recently learned that [genetic algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algebra) are a thing, which means there is a link between abstract algebra and genetics.

*Question*: What should I (wearing my mathematician's hat) know about them?

Essentially, I want to go from "I know nothing about them" to "I have a superficial understanding, but know where to look if I want to know more" (or maybe "I know what to say if someone asks me about them at a conference" [#overlyhonestmethods](https://twitter.com/#overlyhonestmethods)).  What's the motivation?  What's a toy example?

There's definitions on the Wikipedia page, but "set with [operations, homomorphisms, etc.] satisfying [list of axioms]" doesn't give much insight.

Comment: As stated, the question seems hard to answer. Looking at the definition, they're algebras and hence, to me, your question says: "What should I know about algebras with a certain property?" Well, it depends. What are you planning to do with them? It seems like you actually want to ask about the role that genetic algebras play in a certain field - say biology. And this question doesn't belong on MSE.

Comment: My colleague mentioned these came up in his research studying isotopies of algebras, and I had never heard of them before.  I'm wondering if it's worth investing my time studying them more in depth, and if so, which aspects would be most relevant to focus on.  I'm playing the role of a student here.  It's an "in between" topic, requiring both mathematical and biological understanding, but my impression of the literature is that it's more mathematical, with a biological motivation (with most papers I'm aware of published in mathematical journals).

Comment: So, in actuality, your question is whether they're interesting objects to study? That question certainly makes sense and argueably is appropriate to ask on MSE (- despite being primarily opinion based). However, it's an entirely different question from the one you asked.

Comment: Wörz-Busekros, Angelika. Algebras in genetics, Lecture Notes in Biomathematics, 36, 1980, is often quoted as an entry to the subject. For mathematicians of course, since the subject is pure maths.